# Нужна ли первая запятая

Tags: пунктуация

*В помощь cоставляющим перечень, фирма составила свои теоретические рекомендации, опираясь на опыт предшественников.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, не нужна, совершенно незачем она.